# How to render markdown content with jinja2, in a django project?

Tags: python, markdown, jinja2

I am working on a django project with a model like:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    # which is submitted by users through a markdown editor.
    content = models.TextField(_('content'), blank=True)
    ...
```

As a result, I render the content in the templates with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), what I get is only raw markdown content without any style.

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd,thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Not sure about Django, but I use Markdown with Jinja2 in flask.  I initialize Markdown when the app runs like this.

#### app

```
from flask.ext.markdown import Markdown
md = Markdown(app, extensions=['fenced_code'])
```

Then I add the filter to the template.

#### template

```
<H2>{{ post.title }}</H2>
{{post.body|markdown}}
```

In short, do you have the template filter set?

Comment: Thanks a lot,Jinja is a wonderful thing. I just need to customize a    filter simple as :`def markup(text, *args, **kwargs):
    from markdown import markdown
    return markdown(text, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @Foxjack, if you are satisfied with the answer please accept it. Thanks.